# How to use app shell in Angular 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want my app to have instant loading time, by using app shell (progressive web app) that is cached in browser, and later to fill this with data.

But, all examples and libraries on net are angular 2 apps. How to make an app shell for angular 1 app which is pretty big - 1.5mb minified.

Comment: did you find a solution to this